# Group by date and another column and apply value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is a sample of my data for one month (i can't provide more) :

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">CREATEDDATE</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">ISCONVERTED</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">08 August 20</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">01 January 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">02 February 21</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The column `ISCONVERDED` take `[0 or 1]` : if it's converted or not.

What i would like to do is to groupe by date, for each date I will have the percent when  `ISCONVERTED` = `'1'` and the purcent when `ISCONVERTED` = `'0'`, like this :

```
| CREATEDDATE     | ISCONVERTED |
|-----------------|-------------|
| 01 January 21   | 1.000000    |
| 02 February 21  | 0.676471    |
| 02 February 21  | 0.323529    |
| 03 March 21     | 0.598909    |
| 03 March 21     | 0.401091    |
| 04 April 21     | 0.646900    |
| 04 April 21     | 0.353100    |
| 05 May 21       | 0.678363    |
| 05 May 21       | 0.321637    |
| 06 June 21      | 0.729231    |
| 06 June 21      | 0.270769    |
| 07 July 21      | 0.646586    |
| 07 July 21      | 0.353414    |
| 08 August 20    | 1.000000    |
| 08 August 21    | 0.553247    |
| 08 August 21    | 0.446753    |
| 09 September 21 | 0.597911    |
| 09 September 21 | 0.402089    |
```

I tried this piece of code :

```
df= df.groupby(['CREATEDDATE'])['ISCONVERTED'].value_counts(normalize = True)
```

The result shown like this :

[image]

Have you any idea, how i could resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's missing from your current solution.
If you just need a DataFrame, you can reset the index so that:

```
df= df.groupby(['CREATEDDATE'])['ISCONVERTED'].value_counts(normalize = True).rename('RATIO').reset_index()
```

If you'd rather have only two columns as shown in your question you just need to then remove the ISCONVERTED column:

```
df= df.groupby(['CREATEDDATE'])['ISCONVERTED'].value_counts(normalize = True).rename('RATIO').reset_index()
del df['ISCONVERTED']
```

Comment: sorry : I have already tested this code, but it only provides part of the result i.e. when ISCONVERTED = 1 and not the rest of the result when ISCONVERTED = 0

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you were looking for (since ISCONVERTED = 0 is by definition 1 - (ISCONVERTED = 1).

Comment: when i try your second piece of code like i did in my code, i have this error : ValueError: cannot insert ISCONVERTED, already exists

Comment: You're right. I'll edit one last time. The problem was the series name (IS_CONVERTED) is also the name of one of the index.

Comment: GREAT, now it's work with the new column RATIO like you did in your  codes. the solution : reset index + create a new column , thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this in that way:

```
df = df.groupby(['CREATEDDATE'])['ISCONVERTED'].value_counts(normalize = True).unstack(fill_value=0)

df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
df = df.melt(id_vars=['CREATEDDATE']).sort_values(by='CREATEDDATE', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.rename(columns={'variable':'VALUE', 'value':'PERCENTAGE'})
```

Output:

```
        CREATEDDATE   VALUE  PERCENTAGE
0     01 January 21     0        0.00
1     01 January 21     1        1.00
2    02 February 21     0        1.00
3    02 February 21     1        0.00
4       03 March 21     0        0.30
5       03 March 21     1        0.70
6       04 April 21     0        1.00
7       04 April 21     1        0.00
8         05 May 21     0        1.00
9         05 May 21     1        0.00
10       06 June 21     0        0.50
11       06 June 21     1        0.50
12       07 July 21     0        1.00
13       07 July 21     1        0.00
14     08 August 20     1        1.00
15     08 August 20     0        0.00
16     08 August 21     1        0.00
17     08 August 21     0        1.00
18  09 September 21     0        0.25
19  09 September 21     1        0.75
```